# Have you used DiffVue? It is a diff utility but I don't know much about it

Tags: diff, comparison

When I search download.com, I found this diffvue software, and it sounds quite promising with cheap price. But its size is huge comparing to other software. I tested only a basic things and I like that I can create a single PDF file and I can compare non-text files, such as, Word / Excel / etc. Now I have to decide whether I have to pay $20 for this or if there is other diff utility with a reasonable price or preferably free. :)

Comment: We use Beyond Compare - it's commercial, but excellent. http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Answer (score 1):

i've used it for a while. i used to use an old version of beyondcompare and tried to upgrade to the latest one, but it was kind of comlicated to me. so i downloaded diffvue and it should have been expired since i installed it more than a month ago, but it is still full functional. i got "expired" message once in a while. as a cad engineer and developer, i need to compare cad files but i haven't found any software that can compare non text file except diffvue. that's right. you can create a pdf file using diffvue. it highlights all lisp and c++ syntax as well as other formatted files. a few days ago, i got a message in systray that the update was available so i updated it. the newer version has ftp comparison utility. the newer version wasn't available in download.com though.

i am as stingy as you are, so i am going to keep using it until i get tired of "expired" message. good luck.